# no class def found although testng jar shows up under maven dependencies

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng

I have included the testng dependency in pom. The jar gets downloaded on updating project. The jar is visible under maven dependencies. But when i run the code I get

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/TestNG at com.sample.maven.mvntest.App.main(App.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.TestNG

My code is as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    ArrayList<String> suites = new ArrayList<String>();
    suites.add(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\config\\testng.xml");
    testng.setTestSuites(suites);
    testng.run();
    
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you run your code?

Comment: I run as java application